How to add a FancyBbox as a legend?
As per the title, I'm trying to add a list of fancy bboxes to a legend : https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/shapes_and_collections/fancybox_demo.html.
I tried the code below but there is a problem. The shapes are not the same.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import FancyBboxPatch

styles = ['darrow', 'round4', 'roundtooth', 'square']
coords = [(0.2, 0.2), (0.2, 0.8), (0.8, 0.2), (0.8, 0.8)]
colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'orange']
weights = ['bold', 'ultralight', 'normal', 'heavy']

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

patches = []
for style, color, weight, (x, y) in zip(styles, colors, weights, coords):
    ax.text(x, y, style, fontsize=12, fontweight=weight, ha='center', va='center', bbox=dict(boxstyle=style, facecolor=color, alpha=0.5, edgecolor='black'))
    legend_patch = FancyBboxPatch((0, 0), width=1, height=1, boxstyle=style, facecolor=color, edgecolor='black', alpha=0.5, transform=ax.transAxes, label='Bbox')
    patches.append(legend_patch)

ax.legend(patches, styles, loc='center', handleheight=2)

plt.show()

Can you guys show me how to fix my code ?

